# Resulting pressure of batteries in series

Tags: mechanical-engineering, battery

Hi everyone we are working on a battery project and have the following question. What is the influence of stacking battery cells next to each other in a battery module on the resulting pressure exerted on the two walls clamping the cells?

The cells will want to expand when charging but are restricted by fixed walls, this will generate pressure. At first glance, it seems obvious that the resulting pressure will be $P_{module} = n \cdot P_{cell}$
, but after some discussions with my colleagues, we see that different interpretations of the representation of the battery will lead to different results.

(in the picture it might look like the cell has halved in size, but the cells are all identical)

[image: Two cell stacking]

[image: One Cell stacking]

Comment: Follow the energy.  If you have more cells, are you pumping in more energy?

Comment: Yes if you are placing two cells in series there will be twice as much energy pumped into the cells.

Comment: You will just have to do the math on the matter in the cells and how they react to the energy. Getting confused by representations and cell divisions won't help.  Suppose you have x kg of a material (go with ideal gas as an example if you want simplicity); add y J of energy.  Figure out where the energy went (temperature, losses, relation between pressure and volume as imposed by a container, etc) based on how you added the energy and derive the change in pressure.